How to Print a PDF with Ansarada Restrictions
I have a PDF file that is encrypted with Ansarada. The restrictions set on the file prevent me from editing, printing, or copying the document. However, I need to print the file for a submission.
I have tried methods such as using GhostScript and PikePdf, but Ansarada restrictions prevent me from opening the PDF with any tools other than Adobe Acrobat.
Has anyone found a way to bypass these restrictions? Previously, I could print the PDF because the restrictions were only on editing or copying. However, now I have received a file with printing restrictions as well. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Assuming the PDF owner has set these restrictions, and you are not the owner, this is a legal gray area. Also, if you "must" submit this PDF then the owner or person who requires you to submit it should have a way for you to do that legitimately.

I have engaged in a Individual Recipient Confidentiality Undertaking with the client to access the pdf. I never had this issue as I was able to print the file before and then I'd handwrite and highlight comments and then scan it.
